# Shell command not found in python script

Tags: python, csh

I source a dotcshrc file in my python script with :os.system(‘/bin/csh dotcshrc’) and it works,but when I want to use the command I have just put into the env by the source command,like os.system(‘ikvalidate mycase ‘),linux complaints:command not found.
But when I do it all by hand,everything go well.
Where is problem?

Comment: you should properly format your code snippets https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: sorry about that，I type all these by my phone..

Comment: I solved this issue by submitting the task to a Perl script to get away from python os.system problem. I guess Perl use csh command,not sh command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a command in linux like `ls` and you want to use it in your python code do like this:

```
import os
ls = lambda : os.system('ls')
# This effectively turns that command into a python function.
ls() # skadoosh!
```

Output is :

```
FileManip.py                          Oscar
MySafety                              PROJECT DOCS
GooSpace                              Pg Admin
l1_2014                               PlatformMavenRepo
l1_2015                               R
l1_201617                             R64
l2_2014                               Resources
```

Comment: thats pretty cool but doesn't really answer the question, and OP is already using `os.system`

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` runs each command in its own isolated environment. If you are sourcing something in an `os.system` call, subsequent calls will not see that because they are starting with a fresh shell environment. If you have dependencies like the above, you might be able to combine it into one call:

```
os.system(‘/bin/csh "dotcshrc; ikvalidate mycase"’)
```

Comment: This doesn’t work either,still camplains :sh :ikvalidate command not found . I thought after the source command linux should have recognized the ‘ikvalidate ‘，but it does not

Comment: its because you are using `csh` but `os.system` uses `sh`. You might have to enclose it in quotes to tell `csh` to run everything. does `os.system(‘/bin/csh "dotcshrc; ikvalidate mycase"’)` work?

Comment: You are right.But the .cshrc is not under my control.So I must use the Csh. I have tried subprocess,doesn’t work either.